# Cocos2d-x RenderTexture context lost after game resume on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use RenderTexture in my game, and it lost its context after resume the game from background in Android. The same bug is in Cocos2d-x CppTests for "Node: RenderTexture" test.

It is possible to restore textures loaded from file, but how to restore generated texture from RenderTexture?

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When an Andorid application is backgrounded the OS may free all of the graphics resources to stop all of the platform's memory being consumed. Because the resources are freed, there is nothing to restore from, except the file on disk.

Comment: thanks! I'll try to save image in file or memory object before going to background and restore it on resume.

Comment: Storing it into a memory object would defeat the point of freeing the graphics memory to ensure the foreground process gets the resources it needs (and may result in background processes being killed, rather than just backgrounded).